# When I completely remove ClamAV, ClamD stays behind

Tags: server, sudo, debian, clamav, purge

Also, it takes up 50% CPU a lot of the time on my small VPS, is that normal, and how do I remove clamd without just deleting it from usr/sbin etc?

Answer (score 8):

`clamav` frontend and `clamd` install separately from each other as binary packages for some odd reason.

`sudo apt remove clamav-daemon clamdscan python{,3}-pyclamd` should work to remove the remnants of ClamD from the system.

Comment: getting "Unable to locate package python-pyclamd" when running above command. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: @sifar because Python 2 packages were more or less pruned.  Replace `python{.3}-pyclamd` with `python3-pyclamd` instead for your issue.  Apologies that this never was on my radar of notifications.